# Change connection string for all of projects in a solution

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 projects in one solution. How can I change both connection string in one of them?

Answer (score 1):

Have the connectionstring in one project and expose it by a method that returns the connectionstring. The other project references the first and uses that method at all places that require a connectionstring.

Be aware, that this only makes sence if both projects can be referenced logically. If not use a third project, that only contains the connectionstring and exposes it by such method.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is a shared app.config and this can be done very easily with [linked files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306234) within Visual Studio.

In the screenshot below you can see how it's done:
[image: Add As Link]

Comment: Can you make your question more clear? Do you have 2 exe's that need to share the same connectionstring? And you only want to configure it once?